# Mapping c arrays

Tags: c, arrays, swift, interop

How can a C struct like

```
typedef struct {
    double a;
    int8_t b[5];
    int32_t c;
} Foo;
```

sucessfully be modelled in Swift? (fixed width integers for unambiguity, feel free to replace with `char` and `int` in your head)

When importing a C struct into Swift, statically sized arrays will be converted to tuples and the memory layout is guaranteed to be identical. Going the other way however is not as easy, because it requires us to manually specify potentially long tuple types.

To clarify: The above struct could be modelled as

```
struct Foo {
  var a: Double
  var b: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)
  var c: Int32
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this process, e.g with a preprocessor macro or a special type like c++'s `std::array`? For example, something like this:

```
struct Foo {
  var a: Double
  var b: C_CHAR_ARRAY(5)
  var c: Int32
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of questions in your post so I will try to answer all of them.

The layout of a struct in Swift is not source ordered like in C so you cannot write the same struct representation in Swift. The compiler can pack and rearrange it as desired. So if you want the C layout you have to use C to define the struct.

As for an easy way for making a tuple of a certain number of elements, there isn’t an easy way to do that. You can either define it in C, hand write what you need, or use a tool like Sourcery to generate it.